# Event Parameters List

Tags: events, sapui5

I am trying to understand what exactly is stored in an event using the SAPUI5 documentation [here](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.base.Event.html#getParameter). Where can I find a list of parameters that come with an Event? For example, I just found out that DatePicker has a parameter called "valid", but how would I know that? Surely I wouldn't have to use `getParameters()` for every entity right? Also when you define a function to be called in XML, do they all send the same Event type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general the parameters depend on the intention of the event, e.g. a change event which indicates that the source object has changed its value contains other parameters than an event which informs you that a file upload has failed.

You'll find the available event parameters in API documentation. To stick with your example: Check the API documentation of the [DatePicker](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.DatePicker.html) control, select the [change](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.DatePicker.html#event:change) event from the available events and check the available parameter. You will find the parameter `valid` with a description. To see the difference between the events you may also check the [ListBase](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ListBase.html#constructor) implementation, which defines a bunch of events.

It is good style to use `getParameter` in your event handler to access the parameters values.

```
onDatePickerChanged : function(event) {
    let validDate = event.getParameter("valid");
}
```